# Unable to start an ad-hoc with WPA protection

Tags: networking, wireless, encryption, adhoc

I have a problem. I recently reinstalled Ubuntu 15.10 on my laptop, and I want to create a new ad-hoc. However, under Wi-Fi security, I am stuck with only WEP encryption. I have no idea what caused this, but when I previously installed Ubuntu on this machine, both WPA and WPA2 encryption were available to use on my ad-hoc.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: I do not have a full-blown answer for you, but maybe you need to install some proprietary firmware that you had on your previous setup? I checked my Ubuntu MATE 15.10 and I could select "WPA/WPA2 personal" after selecting ad-hoc network on the previous tab.

Comment: I just found this link for you: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Adhoc#Encryption

Comment: I haven't installed any proprietary firmware with my previous setup. I'll try toying around in the Additional Drivers tab.

Comment: Well I am able to edit the ad-hoc configuration file by using nano on /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NAME and set it to WPA2 from there, but this still does not answer my question of why I still am unable to select it from the dropdown menu from the Ad-Hoc configuration.

Comment: Sorry, I have no further ideas. Just wanted to assure you I see WPA2 in my screen on Ubuntu MATE 15.10 with an Intel WiFi card.